# D3 Pie Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"

Tags: d3.js

Keep getting a console error of 
Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"

Re-created the error here.
http://jsfiddle.net/9f9wonoc/

```
var width = 360;
var height = 360;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = {
'Pass': '#66B51B',
'Fail': '#d03324'
}

var data = [
{ label: 'Pass', count: 12 },
{ label: 'Fail', count: 10 },
];

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +  ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.value(function(d) { return d.count; })
.sort(null);

var path = svg.selectAll(".arc")
.data(pie(data))
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "arc");

path.append("path")
.attr("d", arc)
.style("fill", function(d) { return color[d.data.label]; });

path.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d, i) + ")";
})
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) { return d.data.count; });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one small thing :

you need to set the inner radius 0 as below:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius).innerRadius(0);
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/9f9wonoc/1/)

Hope this helps!